# Bug when drawing Ghost of Winterbash Past Hat on the top-bar

Tags: bug, top-bar, winter-bash-2013

I'm convinced that **there's a bug that occurs when you alternate between tabs** that causes the *Ghost of Winterbash Past* hat to be draw over itself again, causing the hat to be *brighter* and *blurred*.

First, let me show you the visual effect of the bug and after that I'll go into the details of how to reproduce the problem:

[image]

These images were captured from different tabs. **Notice how the *golden crown* of the mask thickens after each image**. If you compare the first image with the last the difference between them is pretty clear.

The problem manifests itself when we use 2 tabs in the browser. I tested the steps below with a few other hats, not all of them, but this only seems to happen with *Ghost of Winterbash Past*. I managed to reproduce this problem with **Firefox** 25.0.1, **Safari** 6.1.1 and **Chrome Canary** 34.0.1759.0.

**Please follow these instructions to the best of your ability, no matter how crazy it sounds:**

> 1) Make sure you are wearing the *Ghost of Winterbash Past* hat.
>
> 2) Open a new tab (aka. **tab #1**) using one of the browsers mentioned above, and access this address: [How to detect a Christmas Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20772893/176769)

[image]

> 3) Select the URL at the *address bar* of **tab #1** (if it's not already selected) and open a new tab to access the same page as before. This will be known as **tab #2**.

**Note:** leaving the URL selected in tab #1 is crazy... yet, essential!

[image]

> 4) After the page on **tab #2** is loaded, select the URL in the *address bar* and press ENTER to reload the page.
>
> 5) Now go to **tab #1** and you should be able to see a thicker golden crown. Alternate between tabs to make it easier to spot the problem.

[image]

> 6) **If nothing happened** at step 5: go to **tab #1** and select the URL. Then go to **tab #2**, select the URL and press ENTER. You can repeat this step one or two times to make the drawing look even thicker.

I never had to execute step 6 more than twice to reproduce the problem.

**Can anybody else confirm this bug?**

Comment: I could only reproduce the problem using the URL I suggested above. I was unable to make it happen with other Stackoverflow posts. Maybe it's interesting to state that I was the one that asked the question and that there's no official answer so far. I don't know if these things influence the result, but I thought you should know, maybe you could test this with your own unanswered questions on Stackoverflow.